# .Net MVC WebApi and Angular2

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api2

I'm developing for the first time an Angular2 application that use an MVC .Net webapi for the backend logic.

My question is?

How can I manage user session and authentication in the application?

Thanks to support

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use bearer Token in Web API and store that in localstorage at client side send them in every request to webapi to validate that.

For token generation you can use [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/token-based-authentication-using-Asp-Net-web-api-owin-and-i/)

For Angular localstorage you can use [this library](https://github.com/phenomnomnominal/angular-2-local-storage)